# Buttons change font of a DIV, font choices unique to HTML page

Tags: javascript

I am looking to use buttons to change the font-family of a common DIV. 
A lot of the solutions have the fonts listed in the javascript function, but we are providing character maps on font product pages, so the font needs to be specified in the HTML.

Here is the HTML:

```
<button onclick="changeFont('Font 1'); ">Font 1</button>
<button onclick="changeFont('Font 2'); ">Font 2</button>
<button onclick="changeFont('Font 3'); ">Font 3</button>
<div class="character-map" style="font-size: 36pt;">Text</div>
```

Here is the javascript:

```
<script>
    function changeFont(font){
        document.getElementById("character-map").style.fontFamily = font.value;
    }
</script>
```

Please let me know if you have any questions, happy to help.

Dan,

Comment: What is wrong with your approach? I think `font.value` should just be `font` because you are passing a string, and `character-map` should be the `id` of the div not the `class`

Comment: Are you asking why the code you have posted does not work? Or are you looking for some other solution? Your question is not clear.

Comment: Changed both of these items and it works beautifully! Thank you de hart

Answer (score 0):

```
 onclick="changeFont('Font 1')
```

You call method 'changeFont' with params: 'Font 1' - string.
In method `changeFont(font)` you must use parameter `font` (its string - 'Font 1')
But you write `font.value`. String haven't value.
So, right way to write this

```
function changeFont(font){
        document.getElementById("character-map").style.fontFamily = font
```

```js
function changeFont(font){
        let el = document.querySelector(".character-map")
        el.style.fontFamily = font;
    }
```

```html
<button onclick="changeFont('Georgia, serif'); ">Font 1</button>
<button onclick="changeFont('Gill Sans, sans-serif'); ">Font 2</button>
<button onclick="changeFont('cursive'); ">Font 3</button>
<div class="character-map" style="font-size: 36pt;">Text</div>
```

And last. Read please about catching nodes in DOM. You try to `getElementById` but your element haven't id, only `class="character-map"`

Answer (score 0):

So there are three thing which I found may be the problem

1. In changeFont function you need to use only font instead of font.value
2. You need to specify character-map as ID attribute instead of class for DIV, As class selector may return multiple nodes as result, It would be good to use ID selector if we are targeting only specific node in UI
3. Font value should be valid font-family to reflect in UI.

Please refer below

```
<button onclick="changeFont('serif'); ">Font 1</button>
<button onclick="changeFont('Cursive'); ">Font 2</button>
<button onclick="changeFont('fantasy'); ">Font 3</button>
<div id="character-map" class="character-map" style="font-size: 36pt;">Text</div>

function changeFont(font){
    document.getElementById("character-map").style.fontFamily=font;
}
```

Comment: This worked great! Thanks so much for posting this solution.